# Redirect to a different folder with the same file name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am renovating a website and I am encountering a problem with URLs that are already indexed in search engines.
These URLs have this path:

```
https://www.example.com/products/product-1
https://www.example.com/products/product-2...
```

And in the new website the path changes to:

```
https://www.example.com/items/product-1
https://www.example.com/items/product-2
```

The `product-1`, `product-2` still retains the name but changes the folder `/products` with `/items`.

How can I do this in `.htaccess` so that those URLs already indexed do not give error 404 and redirect to the `/items` folder?

Comment: Please do add your existing tried htaccess in your question, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following using mod_rewrite at the top of your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^products($|/.*) /items$1 [R=301,L]
```

(You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive if it already occurs in the file.)

The 301 (permanent) redirect ensures that any SEO value of the old URL is preserved. Search engines will see the redirect and index the new URL instead.

However, please test with 302 (temporary) redirects first to avoid potential caching issues.

The above redirects:

- `/products` to `/items`
- `/products/` to `/items/`
- `/products/<something>` to `/items/<something>`

But does **not** redirect:

- `/products<something>`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!